# Why magento is stripping the port number for REST API calls

Tags: magento

Ive just started with magento REST API and Im terrified on learning and observing that magento is responding with: "404 not found" if u have port number other than 80. For some reason, I cant use port 80.

Any solution to this plz...

Thanx in advance

**EDIT:** Adding the URL Im trying to access: `http://localhost:8888/magento/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" . urlencode(http://localhost:8888/magentorest/restcallback.php)`

Comment: Please show the URL you are trying to call. Always try to provide more information.

Comment: ok...here it is: "http://localhost:8888/magento/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" . urlencode(http://localhost:8888/magentorest/restcallback.php);

Comment: So Magento is properly set up to be served on port 8888?

Comment: yah....I have also developed one extension earlier with the same magento configuration(port, verison, etc.). Everything is working fine. This problem is also mentioned in many other forums